# Return or detach from Catalyst controller action?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Let's assume I have the following action in a `Catalyst::Controller` that requires the parameter `bar` to be present. If this parameter is not given in the query I want to show an error message:

```perl
sub foo : Local {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    if (!$c->req->params->{bar}) {
        $c->stash->{error} = "Parameter 'bar' missing!";
        $c->detach; # or return; ?
    }

    # some more logic...
}
```

Now my question is: does it make a difference whether I do `$c->detach` or simply `return` from the action? At first glance the behaviour seems to be identical, but are there any advantages or disadvantages of either option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`detach()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst#$c-%3Edetach()) :

> The same as `forward()`, but doesn't return to the previous action
> when processing is finished. When called with no arguments it escapes
> the processing chain entirely.

Inspecting the source, see [line 278](https://metacpan.org/release/HAARG/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90129/source/lib/Catalyst/Dispatcher.pm#L278), we see that `detach()` throws a `Catalyst::Exception::Detach` exception and thus never returns to the caller.

So using `$c->detach()` is not the same as calling `return` to return from the action sub. Calling `return` will continue the action processing chain, while `$c->detach()` will not.